# Questions about std::list C++

Tags: c++, list, stl, std

I'm new to the whole stl business and I have one question. Before using stl my list nodes would be like this :

```
Class node
{
    int duration;
    string name;
    node * next;
    node * previous;
};
```

So my question is that when I m about to use stl do i need the `node * next` and `node * previous` or they are completely useless since std::list makes ammend for them with their own next and previous functions?

And one more question, do you guys prefer using std::list or making your own? Because this is gonna be my first time using std::list and Im quite buffled.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: std::list is rarely used in practice. What's your use case?

Comment: @Karoly Horvarth I have an assignment and using stl is allowed this time compared to previous ones and I was wondering if it is the way to go. Thanks for your time

Comment: *"do you guys prefer using std::list or making your own?"* - why would you reinvent the STL?

Comment: Use the standard library containers unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise. You'll have fewer errors, your code will be more readable to others, will probably perform better, and (once you learn the standard library) you won't have to copy over or rewrite your implementations and possibly modify them for the new case (perhaps breaking them).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: If you have statistics about worldwide usage of `std::list`, please share your source of information. Will be interesting to know.

Comment: @LogicStuff I dont have experience with c++ and thought that stl list would be badly designed. Thats why I want some opinions on this before proceeding with my assignment.

Comment: Also, by the way (and in partial response to @AdiLevin), there's a case that linked lists [perform worse than sequential containers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo) in practice even for large problem sizes. Linked lists may still be preferable in some cases when they are a more straightforward abstraction of the data, though, especially when they don't constitute a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @Q_M In what way did you think it would be badly designed?

Comment: @alcedine I read something about complexity but didnt give much attention since I prefered opinions from experienced programmers like you.

Comment: @Q_M Performance-wise, you should assume that the standard containers are fine unless you empirically observe that they are not. If you're still worried, test. [*Do not* trust intuition on the subject of performance](https://youtu.be/ea5DiCg8HOY?t=5m30s). You'll end up having to do less work and have better reliability even if you occasionally have to redo something (and really, you probably won't).

Comment: @alcedine I see, thanks for answering!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't need `next` and `previous`, `std::list` implements internally the whole linked list mechanism. just:

```
Class node {
  int duration;
  string name;
};
```

and define your list as:

```
std::list<node> myList;
```

Even better use a `std::vector` instead of `std::list` which outperforms in most situations the `std::list` as it renders more cache friendly.

```
std::vector<node> myVec;
```

Another option would be to use a `std::pair` instead of defining your own `struct`:

```
std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>> myList;
```

However, use of `std::pair` here is cleary subjective. I find it more handy to use `std::pair` instead of defining `struct`s with two member variables, due to the fact that I can see the element type of my STL data-structure at the place where is defined.

Comment: Do you think it is better to use stl or make your own list?

Comment: Why write your own code when somebody has done it for you (and it has been tested)? Enjoy the early lunch

Comment: @Q_M Definitely STL and in particular `std::vector`.

Comment: A bit harsh because it's not part of the question, but I'll have to downvote for the suggestion of pair. That just abandons clarity for the sake of saving a struct declaration, which is not in any way a good tradeoff.

Comment: @Cubic Bit harsh indeed. IMHO we are both subjective here, as I consider `std::pair` clearer and more readable, since with `std::pair` I know the element type of the vector/list at the place of definition, that is I don't have to run back and forward to the definition of `Node` to see its members e.t.c. Plus I don't have to define another `struct` as you've already mentioned, plus I'm benefiting from STL optimizations.

Comment: @101010 You know what's in the vector type wise, but you lose the ability to _name_ the members. I suspect that you wouldn't seriously suggest replacing all methodless structs with `std::tuple`s, so why do it here?

Comment: Not sure `std::pair` makes the code more readable. Using your own class with named members aids in self documenting code.

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm a big fan of yours :). Your solutions saved the day many times at work ;). A big thanks for that. I couldn't argue against the sensei, I'll rephrase the answer to show that this is my opinion and not streamline.

Comment: @101010: I like *fun* too.

Comment: @LokiAstari hahaha, sorry not a native speaker :).

Answer (score 0):

As 101010 tells, that's the case. Also remember the performance of stl list is good since the allocator they use for those is optimized for memory management.

The classical "add of nodes" routine is mostly implemented as a single allocation (with new (C++) or malloc (C)). Nevertheless you can improve that through static arrays or laying data on vectors and pointing to them. I'm just telling in case you want to build something your own and compare performance.

Also let me note that you are using a double linked list. In many cases you only need one iterator per block stl has the forward_list container.

Answer (score 0):

No, your elements of a `std::list` do not need to have `next` and `previous` members.   `std::list` takes care of such bookkeeping internally.

Generally, I will use a standard container rather than rolling my own, unless I have some particular requirements that the standard containers really don't meet.    If `std::list` is the one that is best suited - it often isn't, but is sometimes - I use that.

Although there is some learning value in trying to create your own containers, that sort of thing is not productive in the long run.   The standard containers - assuming a quality implementation - are better than most people can do on their own.